# Any way to get rid of the DLC nag messages?

Tags: psn, fat-princess

I own Fat Princess but, don't have the DLC and don't really want to buy it.  This usually isn't a problem but, for some reason while on multi-player games I get a "Buy the DLC" popup every time I fight a DLC model or walk over their stuff.  Is there any way to turn this off?  It doesn't take up much screen space but, it's uber annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to get rid of the message was to buy the DLC, not the answer you are looking for but that was all I could do when I tried to remove it as well.

Comment: Yeah, I caved and bought it.  My daughter loves the game, as do I, so the ads were getting frustrating.  Plus I do have to admit the hulk smash of the giant is awesome.

Comment: Ya I found the cost was worth it, even if just to remove the ads. the new hat is fun aswell.